# Contest problem boilerplate lock reason

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, contests, locked-posts

Given our [current contest problem policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy), I would like to request there be a [customised post-notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191981/what-about-site-specific-post-notices) for handling the locking of those questions.

Proposed notice text:

> **This question is locked in view of our [policy about contest questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy).** Questions originating from active contests are locked for the duration of the contest, with any answers hidden from view by [soft-deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221). Please see the comments for references to the originating contest.

As usual: please feel free to edit and/or comment. After the text stabilized I'll forward the request upstairs.

Comment: This means we don't need to edit the question to add the boilerplate message; very nice!

Comment: FWIW: currently we lock using the reason "Content dispute", which often is not the best fit.

Comment: @robjohn: I know that you know that I know that you know. `:-)` My previous comment is for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: I very much support the initiative. It is important that stated reasons for closure be clear, even to fairly new users.

Comment: "hidden from view by soft-deletion" seems redundant; what does "soft-deletion" mean if not "hidden from view"? [It's also a bit of computer-oriented language, which may be unfamiliar to some.] Also, saying "the answers" suggests the answers exist, which need not be the case. I suggest ending the second sentence with "...with any answers hidden from view."

Comment: @Thursday in my mind the point of stressing the *soft* deletion is to imply that the answers  will be restored later so people affected will not complain (that much, it is hoped). However  this is perhaps not very clear in this way. I would end with "...with any answers hidden from view until the end of the contest."

Comment: @quid The sentence already states "for the duration of the contest". I think "A for the duration of B, with C" parses so that "duration" applies to C as well. At any rate, I don't remember any answerers complaining specifically about such deletions.

Comment: @Thursday Fair enough, likely the addition is indeed not necessary.

Comment: @Thursday It was not uncommon so far that the moderator left a comment along the lines of "I'm temporarily deleting this answer until the contest is over" before deleting the answers. That's pretty good in preventing complaints. It may be better to spell it out directly, "... with any answers temporarily deleted", this way the answerers need not know the process to understand the message. [They still need to read the notice, of course, which, as we know, need not be the case.]

Comment: @Thursday: it is redundant since it addresses two different people. For the OP and other low rep users, it is indeed simply "hidden from view". But the answerer will see the post as deleted by a mod. If the answerer is fairly new to the site, I don't know if it is entirely obvious the link between "deletion" and the "hidden from view" in the post notice. Thoughts?

Comment: Now I see the point of mentioning "soft-deletion", and retract previous suggestion. Still think it should be "any answers" instead of "the answers".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Added:

[image: This question is locked in view of our policy about contest questions.]

I tweaked the wording *slightly* to make the rendering a bit more tidy, but for the most part it is what was suggested above.

Reminder: [you can search currently-locked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=locked%3a1%20is%3aquestion).